# Error during adding port to Hortonworks Sandbox

Tags: hdp

I was trying to execute `systemctl enable sandbox.service` command mentioned here [*"How to add ports to the HDP 2.5 VirtualBox Sandbox"*](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/How-to-add-ports-to-the-HDP-2-5-VirtualBox-Sandbox/ta-p/247995).
But I am getting the following error:

```
[root@sandbox-host system]# systemctl enable sandbox.service
Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory
```

The output of running `find /lib/systemd -iname sand*` is the following:

```
[root@sandbox-host system]# find /lib/systemd -iname sand*
/lib/systemd/system/sandbox-container.service
```

Comment: Please note that the tuorial is about 4 years old. Can you edit your question and add the output of `find /lib/systemd -iname sand*`

Comment: @BobaFit, Thanks for your reply. I have updated the question now. Here is the output of the find command:  [root@sandbox-host system]# find /lib/systemd -iname sand*
/lib/systemd/system/sandbox-container.service

Answer (score 1):

The service got renamed. Enter `systemctl enable sandbox-container.service`.